# What are the totem poles used for?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

Since the latest big update there are small totems placed in the maps. Survivors are able to destroy them. Can I do something else with them? Do they have influence on the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those totems are linked to the [Hag](http://deadbydaylight.gamepedia.com/Hag)'s mechanic. It is advised to clean a specific version of those totems:

> Another mechanic unique to the Hag is the cleansing of Totems. Every match, Totems with skulls and lit candles will appear at random locations. When they are cleaned by the survivors, it may remove one of the Hag's perks. It is advised to do so as the Hag has some interesting but yet devastating perks, one of which effects the generators in a negative way.

The totems with the lit candle on them are the cursed ones. They are linked to one of the Hag's perks: [Devour Hope](http://deadbydaylight.gamepedia.com/Devour_Hope), [Ruin](http://deadbydaylight.gamepedia.com/Ruin), [The Third Seal](http://deadbydaylight.gamepedia.com/The_Third_Seal) and [Thrill of the Hunt](http://deadbydaylight.gamepedia.com/Thrill_of_the_Hunt). One specific cursed totem on the map is linked to one specific Hag's perk. If you take the time to cleanse them, it will remove one perk from the Hag, while cleansing the normal totems only award you with bloodpoints. So if you see any of those totems with a lit candle as a survivor, you better cleanse it.

Destroying a totem will award you with 400 bloodpoints. If it's a cursed totem, it will award you with 800 bloodpoints.